# Call Google Apps Script

Tags: go, google-apps-script

I've the below Google Apps script:

```
function doGet(request) {
  var events = CalendarApp.getEvents(
    new Date(Number(request.parameters.start) * 1000),
    new Date(Number(request.parameters.end) * 1000));
  var result = {
    available: events.length == 0
  };
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Once I open the following url at browsr:

```sh
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwNGgAO-p4TrbKLdGj_blwm5nI9nD5i_0EtlnS42-PuVsrxrM3Ovvwfdw/exec?end=1325439000&start=1325437200
```

I get correct responce:

```sh
{"available":true}
```

I'm trying to do the call through Go as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    site := "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwNGgAO-p4TrbKLdGj_blwm5nI9nD5i_0EtlnS42-PuVsrxrM3Ovvwfdw/exec"
    base, err := url.Parse(site)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Path params
    //  base.Path += "this will get automatically encoded"

    // Query params
    params := url.Values{}

    params.Add("start", "1325437200")
    params.Add("end", "1325439000")
    base.RawQuery = params.Encode()

    fmt.Printf("Encoded URL is %q\n", base.String())

    // make a sample HTTP GET request
    res, err := http.Get(base.String())
    // check for response error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // read all response body
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    // close response body
    res.Body.Close()

    // print `data` as a string
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
}
```

But I'm not getting the same output, and getting very long text looks to be like extraction of Google login screen with multiple languages (regardless what the output is, it is not the expected one), I expect the output to be same what I got at the browser, i.e.

```sh
{"available":true}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the settings of your Web Apps? Those are the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access`.

Comment: @Tanaike Web App "Execute as: Me" and "Who has access: Any one with google account"

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you use `Anyone with Google account` for `Who has access`, you, who are the owner of the Web Apps, are required to use the access token. In your golang script, it seems that the access token is not used. And also, when the users who are not the owner of Web Apps access to the Web Apps, it is required to share the Google Apps Script project of Web Apps with the users. I'm worry that these might be the reason of your issue. How about this? And, this report might be useful. https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

Comment: If you want to test the request to Web Apps, I recommend to use the settings of `Anyone with Google account: Me` for `Who has access: Anyone`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, I learned from you today, appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I asked about the settings of `Execute as:` and `Who has access:` in your Web Apps, I confirmed that in your settings, `Execute as:` and `Who has access:` are `Me` and `Any one with google account`, respectively.

In this case, when you, who are the owner of the Web Apps, access to your Web Apps using your script, it is required to include the access token to the request header. But when I saw your golang script, it seems that the access token is not used for the request header. And, when the users, who are not the owner of Web Apps, access to the Web Apps, it is required to use the access token and also share the Google Apps Script project of Web Apps with the users.

I'm worry that these might be the reason of your issue.

If you want to test the request to Web Apps, I recommend to use the settings of `Anyone with Google account: Me` and `Who has access: Anyone`. By this, the script works without using the access token. And also, the users, who are not the owner of Web Apps, can access to the Web Apps without both using the access token and sharing the GAS project.

#### Reference:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)